# "We couldn't create a new partition..." error while installing Windows 8.1 on Samsung 530U

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, bios

So I've been trying install Windows 8.1 on Samsung 530U, but I keep getting this error "We couldn't create a new partition...". I'm using 16GB usb stick that I made with Windows USB/DVD tool. I understand the issue is because the drive Samsung 530U has some kind of SSD/HDD hybrid and the Windows setup is reading it as whole both the HDD part and SSD part. I'm guessing that's why I'm getting the error. My second thought is that I need to get drivers to my USB stick for Windows setup to understand everything?

> Hard drive is an hybrid ssd + mechanical model is : Hitachi HDD:
>   Z5K500-500 / HTS545050A7E380 of 500GB : 16 GB is on SSD and the 
>   remaining part is on mechanical.

I tried this with no luck.

> Resolution:
>
> Try to following methods:
>
> 1)Check if you have an SD Card in the system. If you do, you remove it
>   and run setup again.
>
> 2) Once the setup fails to find the partition, just close the setup
>   window (the top-right-hand side red X does the job).
>
> From that point, you should be brought back at the initial setup
>   screen.Choose "Repair" then go to the advanced tools and start the
>   command line.
>
> Start DISKPART.
>
> Type LIST DISK and identify your SSD disk number (from 0 to n disks).
>
> Type SELECT DISK  where  is your SSD disk number.
>
> Type CLEAN
>
> Type CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY
>
> Type ACTIVE
>
> Type FORMAT FS=NTFS QUICK
>
> Type ASSIGN
>
> Type EXIT twice (one to get out of DiskPart, the other to exit the
>   command line tool)

Comment: I thought I'd try installing Ubuntu, setup is currently installing OS just fine...

Comment: Ubuntu is working just fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there was nothing wrong and it was just my really really stupid mistake. I was using 16GB USB stick and the SSD part on this laptop is also 16GB, so in the partitioning section of the setup it showed the 500GB HDD drive 0 and 16GB drive 1, I thought it was some kind of bug and it was showing me my USB stick(like it does in Ubuntu install for example) so I completely ignored it all the time. After I wiped SSD setup progressed and has been installing just fine so far.

Ater installing I still kept having problems so I kept searching and searching for hours for solution finally I found a guide. http://forum.notebookreview.com/samsung/701927-clean-in...
Did that and still wasn't able to boot up. Did more research and tried again, third time I noticed something in list volumes, drive letters had changed for some reason F: drive that should've been 350MB was 450GB and C: 350MB so I activated C: partition instead and typed bcdboot F:\windows /s C: and it worked!

So problem was mostly me not noticing the little stuff, but everyone who is having problems installing Windows on Samsung 5 or 7 series laptops follow that guide. Would be nice if Windows setup would know how to do that stuff on their own like Ubuntu.

Comment: The link does not exist, do you have any other reference or solution that was described in that guide?